# Printing variable output in one line in loop in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a string given as

> mystring="01-MAY-11 12.07.38.199 PM: 31-APR-13 12.07.38.199 PM:
>   31-JUN-14 12.07.38.199 PM:"

I am iterating the string as

```
IFS=:
for item in $mystring
do
echo    "expdp  query"  "$item"
done
```

My output is :

> expdp  query 01-MAY-11 12.07.38.199 PM
>
> expdp  query
>
> 31-APR-13 12.07.38.199 PM
>
> expdp  query
>
> 31-JUN-14 12.07.38.199 PM

But I want to get the out put like given below

> expdp  query 01-MAY-11 12.07.38.199 PM
>
> expdp  query 31-APR-13 12.07.38.199 PM
>
> expdp  query 31-JUN-14 12.07.38.199 PM

Please suggest what parameters i have to provide while iterating in the for loop

Comment: If copy and paste your string and your loop, I get the output in three lines as wanted. The additional linebreaks have to be in the string or in your scipt. Does a  `dos2unix yourscript` change the output?

Comment: Yes string has additional line break . actually this string output comes from the sql query run the shell script as mystring=`sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF
connect userid/pass@db
set heading off
set feedback off
set echo off
set pagesize 0
select   trim(max(last_timestamp))
       from ( select   t.modify_timestamp||':' as last_timestamp , ntile(3) over (order by t.modify_timestamp) nt
                from table  t where t.modify_timestamp <= sysdate -1000
                )
        group by nt order by nt;
EOF`

Answer (score 0):

file.sh :

```
mystring="01-MAY-11 12.07.38.199 PM: 31-APR-13 12.07.38.199 PM: 31-JUN-14 12.07.38.199 PM:"
IFS=:
first=1
for item in $mystring
do
if [[ $first == 1 ]]; then
    echo "expdp query" " $item"
    first=0
else
    echo "expdp query" "$item"
fi
done
```

./test.sh :

```
expdp query  01-MAY-11 12.07.38.199 PM
expdp query  31-APR-13 12.07.38.199 PM
expdp query  31-JUN-14 12.07.38.199 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add `mystring=$( echo ${mystring} )` to get rid of linebreak within the string by intentionally omit the quoting.

But now that we know about the origin of the linebreaks, using a `while read` seems to be the better option.

```
sqlplus ...... | while read -r item ; do
    echo    "expdp  query"  "$item"
done
```

You may remove the `:` from your query.

If you need more than `echo`, try to avoid this [Bash Pitfall #8](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#grep_foo_bar_.7C_while_read_-r.3B_do_.28.28count.2B-.2B-.29.29.3B_done) (or the longer description [BashFAQ#24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024))